# Improve runtime in code in assembly

Tags: assembly

Consider the following 80X86 code segment. Assume that when the code is run, ECX is non-zero.

```
  L: MOV    AL, [ESI]
 XOR    [EDI], AL
 XOR    AL, [EDI]
 XOR    [EDI], AL
 MOV    [ESI], AL
 INC    ESI
 INC    EDI
 LOOP   L, ECX
```

I need to Re-write the above code segment for better runtime efficiency, under the assumption that ECX initially is divisible by 4.

How do I do that?

Comment: A brief outline of the algorithm would be helpful. Assembly isn't very readable. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
L:
MOV    EAX, [ESI]
XOR    [EDI], EAX
XOR    EAX, [EDI]
XOR    [EDI], EAX
MOV    [ESI], EAX
ADD    ESI, 4
ADD    EDI, 4
SUB    ECX, 4
JZ     L
```

I don't know what assembler you are using, so I tried to write a general example.

Basically, the above algorithm uses the entire EAX register to move 4 bytes at once.